# clojure, ring, tomcat and JSESSIONID

Tags: tomcat, clojure, jsessionid

I have started using Clojure to build a web app (using ring and compojure) and everything is working fine with it.

However, when I use uberwar to create a war file and deploy it to Tomcat, my session is not visible to Tomcat.

The session mechanism itself is definitely working (it's preserving state for a shopping basket, for example) but there is no JSESSIONID and the Tomcat manager app, Java Melody, Psi Probe are all saying I have no sessions.

I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing around creating the JSESSIONID, but I have not seen anything about this in any of the tutorials I have found.

Can someone point me towards an example of how a Clojure app deployed to a Tomcat server creates a JSESSIONID?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ring uses its [own session store](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj).

However, if you are using a Servlet container, Ring will [populate the request map](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj#L51) with the various Servlet objects. In this case, the `:servlet-request` key refers to the `HttpServletRequest` object.

It's worth noting that Ring is an abstraction over HTTP, and doesn't necessarily rely on the Servlet specification. So as long as you use a Servlet container underneath, you should be able to use your Servlet sessions

Comment: Perfect answer thank you.  I've now got a servlet container session up and running following your comment.